# How to fetch API data to Graphql schema

Tags: javascript, php, magento2, graphql

I want to call to API, get json data and set it to resolvers Query in Graphql. So far I managed to working Graphql server and get call to API. This is my code so far

```
//resolvers.js
//var fetch = require('node-fetch');
var request = require("request");


var options = { method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://mydomain.con/index.php/rest/V1/products/24-MB01',
    headers:
        { 'postman-token': 'mytoken',
            'cache-control': 'no-cache',
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            authorization: 'Bearer mytoken' } };

const links = request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    //body = json data
    //console.log(body);

});

module.exports = {
    Query: {
        //set data to Query
        allLinks: () => links,
},
};
```

I dont know how to set the body parameter which contain json data to Query. I have also same data on "http://localhost/src/apicall.php" but this is not working with node-fetch (or Im making mistakes). Api is from magento2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close !

What you are doing right now is sending the `links` request right when your application starts. You don't want that ; you want to send the request when the `allLinks` field is requested in GraphQL.

So what you need is to have in the `allLinks` field a function making the request to your API, and returning the response.

If you return a Promise within the `allLinks` field, it will wait upon completion to use the returned value as an answer.

So, putting it all together:

```
...

const getAllLinks = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) reject(error);
      else resolve(body);
    });
  });
};

module.exports = {
  Query: {
    //set data to Query
    allLinks: getAllLinks,
  },
};
```

Comment: Make sense to me but Im getting Error after running script in Graphql "Error: Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field Query.allLinks." . Maybe the problem is in reponse now? I mean it looks like that: { "id": 1, "sku": "24-MB01", "name": "Joust Duffle Bag", etc} and not like that  { id: 1, sku: "24-MB01", name: "Joust Duffle Bag", etc}

Comment: That means GraphQL was expecting an array-like object but you didn't return one. You are returning a single object, but you did define your type as `[MyType]`, right ?

Comment: My schema: const typeDefs = ` type Link { id: ID! sku: String! } type Query { allLinks: [Link!]! } `; Schema must contains all fields from json data?

Comment: You defined your field `allLinks` as `[Link!]!` so that means you must return an array of links, not a single one. Try doing `resolve([body])`, for example purposes

Comment: Making progress, now "Error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field Link.id."

Comment: So i cant return all items? In example i used json with only 1 product, but when I add "products?searchCriteria=" i get all 1300+ products.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you want to return a single product, then the GraphQL type should be `Link!`. If you want to return a list, the GraphQL type should be `[List!]!`

Comment: Im new in GraphQL, so I dont know. Did I do something wrong in schema?

Comment: What the error is saying is that you returned `null` in the `id` property of your JSON object, but you probably defined your type as `type Link { id: Int!, ...}`. The `!` in `Int!` means you can't return null ;)

Comment: I tried to console log resolve(body) but it shows me `undefined`, so I think this is the problem. It didnt properly set the body to Query.

Comment: @Brunhilda yes that's the pb :)

Comment: So Im still at the beginning.

Comment: Did you console log `resolve(body)` or `body` ? I may have misunderstood. `undefined` is normal for `resolve(body)`, it isn't for `body`

Comment: Anyway I don't understand how you are still having problems at this point, the GraphQL error is pretty clear: you are returning an object without an `id` property set, I don't see how we can help you further, console log `body` and see if the `id` isn't defined as the error is telling you

Comment: Already solved it, the things go wrong is that the response looks like that `{ "id": 1 etc}`, with [body] looks like `['{ "id":1 etc}']`. The problem was not returning response as array or the `''` marks.